# SQLite taking so much time after a resume

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

We have a C++ application written in QT, where on click of a certain row, I call some API (on local system only).
The API is connected through SQLite, now the problem is, if I happen to stop my execution (for more than 5 seconds) and then resume the operation by clicking on UI (QT), it will call the API but this time the sqllite3_exe() will take more than 20 seconds to execute. After this If I continue my operation it will function as fast as it was functioning  (1-3 seconds).
This happens whenever, I'm idle and resume any interaction with UI in terms of calling API and hence sqlite3_exe.

I have tried to check and remove the close connection as well but with no success at all.

Comment: Cache. Your computer is short of memory.

Comment: It has a Xeon processor and 64 GB ram

Comment: What else is running on the machine? MSSQL?

Comment: Nothing else is running, it's running on win 7 pro

Comment: What does Task manager say is happening? Swapping? What about process monitor? What happens if you run it in the debugger and break during the pause?